# Are US citizens allowed to fly anywhere outside the 50 states without a passport?

Tags: air-travel, passports, us-citizens, destinations

For US citizens, are there any locations outside the 50 US states that don't require a passport to fly to and from?

Comment: Are you considering US territories such as Puerto Rico, US Virgin Islands, or Guam? They're outside the 50 states, but not a different country.

Comment: I edited out the infant question.  Please ask it separately.

Comment: Well are you planning to land?  There are several countries that allow you to fly over them without a passport.  for example my friend flies his small plain from NY to Detroit, MI frequently right over Canada.  You can do the same thing over Mexico, and other some of the surrounding islands.  I don't believe Cuba allows that though.

Comment: Do US military bases count?

Comment: @gerrit There are no airports in Washington DC, so it's not possible to fly there with or without a passport.

Comment: @LiamWilliam Flying over without a passport... if that is disallowed, I wonder how they enforce it.

Comment: @dbkk :) If they are nice they send the military after you of course.

Comment: @Justin you are wanting/assuming legal answers correct?

Comment: @vartec I wasn't thinking about Military bases but if you have a valid answer that adds to the topic, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @Liam William Yes I am planning to land and am looking for legal answers.

Comment: @greghewgill Regarding territories: Yes, I am wondering about anywhere outside the 50 states (I updated my question). Would I be able to fly to a US territory without a passport?

Comment: @Justin: Yes, you can fly to U.S. territories without a passport.

Comment: @Doc helicopters land frequently in DC, although I don't know whether any do so other than in government service.

Comment: @phoog Would Medevac helicopters count? They land at the Washington Hospital Center, Children's Hospital, etc. There have also been skydivers at the stadiums!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can re-enter the US if you have proof of citizenship, so that doesn't strictly require a passport -- although it may make your enter procedure more troublesome.

As mentioned above, you can theoretically travel to US territories without a passport, from [answers.usa.gov](http://answers.usa.gov/system/templates/selfservice/USAGov/#!portal/1012/article/3980/Domestic-Travel):

> **For Travel to/from/between U.S. Territories**, **U.S. Citizens and Nationals:**
>
> You need a photo identification or travel document when visiting American Samoa, the Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands (CNMI), Guam, Puerto Rico, or the U.S. Virgin Islands. Your itinerary and/or carrier may require this document to be your passport. You also need proof of citizenship and either a return or onward ticket, or proof of employment in the territory, to visit American Samoa.

Also from that page:

> **For Travel to/from/between Freely Associated States, U.S. Citizens and Nationals:**
>
> You may need a valid U.S. passport, birth certificate, or naturalization papers to enter a Freely Associated State.

If I'm right that covers Palau, Federated States of Micronesia and the Republic of the Marshall Islands.

However, from [visit-palau.com](http://visit-palau.com/aboutpalau/index.cfm):

> All visitors must have a valid passport not less than 6 months from date of expiration and proof of return arrangements. [ ... ]
> Citizens of United States of America, Federated States of Micronesia, Republic of the Marshall Islands, Guam, and the Common Wealth of Northern Marianas Islands with valid passports are issued 1 year Visa upon arrival.

so that's out but from [visit-micronesia.fm](http://www.visit-micronesia.fm/guide/regulation.html):

> U.S. citizens may enter any FSM state with a U.S. passport or proof of U.S. citizenship (birth certificate). Non U.S. citizens must have a valid passport from their country of origin.

So there's another option. I can't find an official page for the Marshall Islands but [passportsandvisas.com](http://www.passportsandvisas.com/visas/marshall%20islands-visa-faq.asp) says you need a passport.

It appears you used to not require a passport for Mexico or Canada but this changed in 2009/2010 and now everyone requires a passport to cross those borders.

Also note, if you're flying, airlines may very well insist on a passport or at least make your life difficult if you don't have one. But technically passport-less travel is possible to the places mentioned above.

I'm not sure how things like privately owned islands work -- could you theoretically fly there without a passport? I'd also imagine you *might* be able to persuade a cruise company to let you helicopter out to their cruise liner and land on that, which might count.

Comment: "You can re-enter the US if you have proof of citizenship, so that doesn't strictly require a passport -- although it may make your enter procedure more troublesome." And it would be breaking the law. 8 USC 1185(b) http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1185#b

Comment: Interesting, I was sure I had read somewhere that US citizens were always allowed to re-enter the country, no questions asked apart from that needed to prove their citizenship. This page: http://www.dhs.gov/crossing-us-borders says 'or other approved travel document' so maybe the law isn't enforced? If the law you quote is enforced then the real answer to the question is simply 'no' probably.

Comment: Well, I think both are true. U.S. citizens are required by law to have a passport to leave and enter (unless they fall under one of the exceptions), but they will always be allowed to enter. I don't know if there are any penalties for breaking the law. I believe that if you show up without a passport, they will give you a stern talking-to and automatically submit a "waiver" for the passport requirement on your behalf.

Comment: @user102008 if the immigration officer waives the passport requirement, then the entry is not unlawful. The (now rather old) CBP inspector's field manual says, for example, "Although technically you are waiving the passport requirement for the Department of State, no form need be completed. In addition, there is no fee collected by INS."  There's also [22 CFR 53.3](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/53.3), but that refers to two subsections of 53.2 that have been deleted, so it's all just a big mess.

Comment: 8 USC 1185b starts "except as provided by the President, [etc]"  One could argue that whatever DHS/CBP does is (by delegation) from the President.

Comment: "privately-owned islands": these are generally part of some sovereign state, which can, and normally will, enforce its immigration laws.  I suppose there could be exceptions.

Comment: @WGroleau That is precisely the case; I don't think anyone would argue against that point.  The exception and so on are mostly established in the code of federal regulations (e.g., [8 CFR 235.1(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/235.1#b), which doesn't mention a waiver explicitly.  It may be mentioned elsewhere; I don't remember.  Even without explicit provision for a waiver, however, the executive branch could claim authority to issue one based on a citizen's fundamental rights.

Answer (score 3):

US, Canadian, and Mexican citizens can fly between the US and Canada on their NEXUS card. http://www.nexus.gc.ca/prog/nexus/menu-eng.html

Comment: Not Mexicans, but US and Canadian citizens yes

Answer (score 2):

US and Canadian citizens can use a NEXUS card to fly between the US and Canada.

In addition, a few Caribbean countries (such as St Lucia and - for Canadians - Bonaire/St Eustatius/Saba) let these nationals in (yes, by air as well) with a birth certificate and photo ID, or a certificate of citizenship/Canadian citizenship card.

Canada also lets US citizens in (flying from anywhere) with a US birth/citizenship/naturalization certificate.

However, for a US citizen to re-enter the US by air, a passport or (coming from Canada) NEXUS card is needed. Same goes for Canadians re-entering Canada by air other than from the US